# Nome do Formato 'name <email@email.com>'

Tags: email, header

Estou começando a trabalhar com pgp, e me deparei com este formato de id

```
name <email@email.com>
```

O mesmo também é usado em formatos Raw de email, para informar o remetente ou destinatário, queria saber o nome se possível do formato.

Comment: Eu acho que isso vem justamente da especificação de formato de emails: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4

Comment: Valeu, era exatamente isso que precisava, não tava sabendo bem onde procurar e o que procurar.